# Blocking sending events from child to parent

Tags: c#, wpf

I have very short contact with the `C#` and `WPF`, although most of the stuff I could find over the Internet. However, I cannot find anything (or don't know how to request google to find it) about blocking sending events to the parent.

I've got an `Image` inside `ScrollViewer`. My point is to create zooming option for the image by using `Ctrl` + mouse wheel, but obviously the scrollbars of the `ScrollViewer` are moving while I am moving mouse wheel (the mouse wheel method is defined within the `Image`). Is there any possibility to block event sent from child to parent when `Ctrl` is down?

Comment: This can be done declaratively entirely in Xaml by triggering properties on the ScrollViewer.  Are you using MVVM and want to avoid lots of code-behind?

Comment: @GarryVass I don't use MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handler for the Image, you should set the event's Handled property to true when Ctrl is pressed. This will prevent the ScrollViewer from handling the mouse wheel event.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx for more information, especially the section entitled "The Concept of Handled."